# Regex like search in mongo db nestex query

Tags: regex, mongodb, whitelist

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using MongoDB to store my data. The two collections have the following format:

**CVE**

```
{
  "Modified" : "2014-09-27T06:55:04.867-04:00",
  "Published" : "2014-09-27T06:55:04.867-04:00",
  "_id" : ObjectId("542923711bb35a10e3053986"),
  "cvss" : "9.3",
  "cwe" : "Unknown",
  "id" : "CVE-2014-3062",
  "last-modified" : "2014-09-29T09:00:35.803-04:00",
  "references" : [
    "http://xforce.iss.net/xforce/xfdb/93540",
    "http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683609"
  ],
  "summary" : "Unspecified vulnerability in IBM Security QRadar SIEM 7.1 MR2 and 7.2 MR2 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via unknown vectors.",
  "vulnerable_configuration" : [ 
    "cpe:/a:ibm:qradar_security_information_and_event_manager:7.1.0",
    "cpe:/a:ibm:qradar_security_information_and_event_manager:7.2.0" 
  ]
}
```

**mgmt_whitelist**

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("548855641bb35a2dc5675244"),
 "id" : "cpe:/a:ibm:qradar_security_information_and_event_manager:7.2.0"
}
```

I'd like to find all the items in CVE with a vulnerable configuration in mgmt_whitelist, which I can easily achieve by using:

```
db.cves.find(
    {'vulnerable_configuration':
        {'$in': db.mgmt_whitelist.distinct('id')}
    }
).sort({Modified: -1}).limit(10)
```

However, the whitelist also contains records like

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54885ff41bb35a2f57a7c567"),
  "id" : "cpe:/a:7-zip:7-zip" 
}
```

which is a CPE format without version. I would like to be able to do a regex-like search, so that these kinds of whitelisted items are also found in the search.

I tried

```
db.cves.find(
    {'vulnerable_configuration':
        {'$in': 
            {'$regex':db.mgmt_whitelist.distinct('id')
        }
    }
).sort({Modified: -1}).limit(10)
```

but that didn't work... What should I do instead?

Thanks in advance,

Pidgey

Comment: For each distinct `whitelist` id, you need to compose a `regex` object, depending on how you need to match. Then you could execute it as: `({ vulnerable_configuration: { $in: [ RegexOne, RegexTwo,...] } })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. To add a regex that contains : and /, I needed to use new RegExp().
So in the end, I use something like this:

```
db.cves.find(
  {'vulnerable_configuration':
    {'$in': 
      [new RegExp("cpe:/a:gnu:bash"),new RegExp("cpe:/a:adobe:acrobat_reader")]
    }
  }
).sort({Modified: -1}).limit(10)
```

It's as shame I can't do everything in one statement (please correct me if I'm wrong), but I can solve that with my code. Thanks for your advice, BatScream

Comment: `new RegExp("cpe:/a:adobe:acrobat_reader")` is bad code. You **must** [regex-quote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript) strings you feed to the regex constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
RegExp.quote = function (str) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&");
};

function startsWithExp(string) {
    return new RegExp("^" + RegExp.quote(string));
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

db.cves.find({
    vulnerable_configuration: {
        $in: db.mgmt_whitelist.distinct('id').map(startsWithExp)
    }
}).sort({Modified: -1}).limit(10);
```

---

In a more advanced scenario you might want to return a mixed list of strings and regular expressions, for increased performance (if necessary - measure if the increased complexity has any real benefits):

```
function cpeStartsWithOrMatches(cve_id) {
    var cpeWithVersion = /:\d+(?:\.\d+)+$/;

    return cpeWithVersion.test(string) ? string : startsWithExp(string);
}
// -----------------------------------------------------------------

db.cves.find({
    vulnerable_configuration: {
        $in: db.mgmt_whitelist.distinct('id').map(cpeStartsWithOrMatches)
    }
}).sort({Modified: -1}).limit(10);
```

---

Alternatively you can construct one big expression:

```
function startsWithAnyExp(strings) {
    return new RegExp("^(?:" + strings.map(RegExp.quote).join("|") + ")");
}

db.cves.find({
    vulnerable_configuration: {
        $regex: startsWithAnyExp(db.mgmt_whitelist.distinct('id'))
    }
}).sort({Modified: -1}).limit(10);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippits, but I'm using Python for my code... I can't seem to get it to work, so far... Any hints to point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out! Thanks a bunch for the hint in the right direction!

Comment: @pidgey What? You are not using Python code in your own answer and are not using Python code in your own question. o_O

Comment: Haha sorry for the confusion, that code is raw mongo queries, not programming code

Comment: If you can use `new RegExp()`, it kind of *is* Javascript. that's what confused me.